# Computer works only in Safe Mode, does not boot in Normal mode

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, graphics-card, safe-mode

While I was using my PC, the screen suddenly entered sleep mode, then said "No Signal" and refused to accept any input, while the screen remained black. I restarted it and Windows said there is a problem and offered to repair it, so I allowed it. It then said the repair is complete and restarted itself, and then comes the problem:

PC starts, beeps one time (the beep that says everything is OK), shows windows logo, almost finishes up loading, the windows logo animation freezes, says "No Signal", the screen goes light black (as in full black but still emits light) and remains that way, unable to be controlled.
I was able to start it then in Safe Mode with Networking, and it works as fine as it could (currently typing from here), but when I try the Normal mode, the same issue occurs. The windows repair program said it is unable to repair, but gave me the following error:

```
Problem Signature 01: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 04: 21199736
Problem Signature 05: AutoFailover
Problem Signature 06: 2
Problem Signature 07: BadDriver
```

I looked up online, but everything suggested I format my PC. I am not sure this is a malware, I rather think this is something related to the hardware, so if someone has an idea if I should change my HDD or if something else may be causing it, please let me know. I updated the NVIDIA GeForce 770 drivers up to date, although it may be the video card, still. Please confirm if there is no option rather than formatting my whole PC (and if that is still going to help?)

Comment: This looks like a problem with your video card driver or hardware. You could try to uninstall the video card driver in safe mode. Maybe it will then run with some low-resolution standard graphics driver. Then try to install the driver again.

Comment: Hello there! Does booting from the Windows Installer boot correctly? If so, it is likely a driver issue. From the Windows Installer you can choose to reinstall windows, removing all software (including problematic drivers), but keep your files.

Comment: Hello! Could you please clarify how to boot from windows installer? I have installed windows from a CD 7 years ago on this PC, however that CD is long gone. Please let me know what my options are, removing all software seems like a preferable solution.

Comment: @houdini37 - The first step would be to download a Windows 7 ISO.  However, if you reinstall Windows 7 from by booting to the installation environment, you will replace not repair the installation that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking, seems like my video card's days are gone. I don't know why that prevented Windows from booting outside Safe Mode, but I completely reinstalled my PC, formatting everything in the memory, and the video card cannot perform, resulting in Code 43 error from Windows, shown in the Device manager. I tried different drivers but it was no use. Maybe after 7 years of use it is time for a new one.